# Listening for NSWorkspace Notifications in Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, notificationcenter, nsworkspace

The simple Swift 4 example below should stop when the computer's display goes to sleep.

```
class Observer {
    var asleep = false

    func addDNC () {
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: NSWorkspace.screensDidSleepNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: notificationRecieved)
    }

    func notificationRecieved (n: Notification) {
        asleep = true
    }
}

let observer = Observer ()
observer.addDNC ()

while (!observer.asleep) {}
print ("zzzz")
```

However, the program gets stuck in the while loop. What am I doing wrong, and what is the proper way to wait for a Notification?

I have tried using a selector (`#selector (notificationRecieved)`, with `@objc` in the function declaration, of course), to no avail.

Comment: If you are going to run it with while, then why would you even need to create an notification observer object in the first place?

Comment: This is just an example. However, i couldn't find a way to check sleep status manually. If there is a way to do it other than using notifications, could you tell me where to find an explanation? Thanks. @ElTomato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a template app in Xcode and modify the ViewController.swift to do this:

```
import Cocoa

class Observer {
    var asleep = false

    func addDNC () {
        NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: NSWorkspace.screensDidSleepNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using: notificationRecieved)
    }

    func notificationRecieved (n: Notification) {
        print("got sleep notification!")
        asleep = true
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let observer = Observer ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        observer.addDNC ()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

The difference between your code and mine is that I'm not doing the wacky sleepy polling thing you're doing (that's going to lead to a spinning pizza cursor), and I'm also setting `observer` to be a property off the `ViewController` object, so the `observer` property sticks around as long as the view controller does.

Comment: Observing a notification with viewDidLoad doesn't sound right.

Comment: The way the `Observer` class is set up, I figured `viewDidLoad` was as good a place as any to call `addDNC`.  If this were my code, I'd probably set up the observer directly without using the separate class.  What were you thinking of?

Comment: Having the observer in an actual app, the way you did it, worked. I think the while loop in my example actually prevented the observer from working by stalling the program. (Replied late because i just realized I didn't mark the question as answered)